# How can I download a file on Django clicking on a widget?

Tags: django, file, download

I have a django project consist in different forms with different fields. Some of them are filefield where I upload files to media based on this class.I just want to make a widget to download the files, so when I am editing in change form if a file has been submit I can click on a button to download. Everytime I click on the button I made I received this error on console: "Not allowed to load local resource:" followed by my local root something like  file:///C:/proyectos/etc

My code is too extensive but I will try to show you most of them:

## Models.py (this class is to upload filefields)

```
class CustomStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    # Almacenamiento nuevo en media
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(location=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'media','companies'), *args, **kwargs)
    
def submission_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # Obtener el nombre comercial de la compañía y el ID del cliente
    company_name = slugify(instance.client.company.comercial_name)
    client_data = f"{instance.client.id}_{slugify(instance.client.name)}_{instance.type_submission.name}"

    # Construir la ruta del directorio
    directory_path = os.path.join(company_name, client_data)

    # Devolver la ruta completa del archivo
    return os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
```

## Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #ENDPOINTS
    path('client-details/<uuid:client_id>/', views.get_contact_details, name='client-details'),
    path('panel/submission/<uuid:submission_id>/change/cancel', views.cancel_submission, name='cancel_submission'),
    path('panel/submission/<uuid:submission_id>/change/no-apply', views.no_apply_submission, name='no_apply_submission'),
    # Ir a pantalla de activación de cuenta
    path('<str:name>/<str:uidb64>/<str:token>/', views.account_activation, name='account_activation'),

    path('panel/submission/<uuid:submission_id>/download/<str:file_path>/', views.download_file, name='download_file'),


    ]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## View.py

```
def download_file(request, file_path):
    print("Ruta del archivo:", file_path)
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_path.replace("\\", "/"))
    print("Ruta completa del archivo:", file_path)
    
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            # response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(file), content_type='application/pdf')

            response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(file), content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)[0])
            response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{os.path.basename(file_path)}"'
            return response
    else:
        print("¡Archivo no encontrado!")
        return HttpResponse('File not found', status=404)
```

## forms.py

```
class DownloadFileWidget(forms.Widget):
    template_name = 'download_widget.html'  # Reemplaza con la ubicación real de tu plantilla
    # def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
    #     output = super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
    #     if value:
    #         file_path = value.url
    #         download_link = f'<a href="{file_path}" download>Descargar archivo</a>'
    #         output += mark_safe(download_link)
    #     return output
    
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        output = super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
        if value:
            file_path = value.path  # Cambia de 'value.url' a 'value.path'
            download_link = f'<a href="{file_path}" download>Descargar archivo</a>'
            output += mark_safe(download_link)
        return output
```

## Download_widget.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% if widget.has_file %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'download_file' file_path=widget.value %}" target="_blank">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit">Descargar archivo</button>
    </form>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method here, it worked in my case.
I am using VUE. the code below is in my Vue component and the other one below it is in my django view.py:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js">
buySheet(){
          axios.post('/buySheet/' + this.sheet.id, { sheetId: this.sheet.id, sellerId: this.sheet.owner }, {
                xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
                xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFTOKEN',
            })
              .then(response => {
                // Handle the success response
                console.log("Sheet saved successfully:", response.data);
                window.location.href = `/download_concerto/${this.sheet.id}/`;

              })
              .catch(error => {
                // Handle the error
                console.error("Error saving sheet:", error);
              });
    },
</script>
```

```
def download_concerto(request, concerto_id):
    concerto = get_object_or_404(Concerto, id=concerto_id)
    # Here, you would include any logic to verify the user's right to access the file
    # For example, check if the user has purchased the concerto
    print(concerto.concerto_file_pdf, concerto.concerto_file_pdf.name)
    return FileResponse(concerto.concerto_file_pdf, as_attachment=True, filename=concerto.concerto_file_pdf.name)
```